# jQuery function to MooTools

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mootools

I'm starting to learn MooTools and so far I found it really hard how to make a code similir to  the jQuery version

```
<span id="clickme" onclick="myFunction(5,46,'add')"/> I'm a span</span>

function myFunction(id,iduser,type){

// ajax request with this values

}
```

In MooTools

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() { 

    $('clickme').addEvent('click', function()
    {
            // ajax request ...
    });

}
```

Comment: How is the first "version" jQuery in any way?

Comment: How to do the same thing in MooTools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

er. what? you already have done the click handler, so why not call your function?

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() { 

    $('clickme').addEvent('click', function() {
          // get from html el
          var a = this.get('data-a'), b = this.get('data-b');

          new Request({
              url: 'someurl/',
              method: 'get',
              onComplete: function() {
                  console.log(this.response.text);
              }
          }).send({a: a, b: b}); // sends somerul/?a=nn&b=nn
    });

});
```

this can work with say `<span id='clickme' data-a='5' data-b='45'>click me</span>`

just read the docs and read some tutorials - plenty of examples comparing ajax in many frameworks. this got posted on twitter today: http://wernancheta.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/performing-ajax-calls-on-jquery-dojo-and-mootools/ - not saying it's goot or whatever but its there.

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event#Element:addEvent